# how to continue download in background after terminate app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

My question is how to continue download in background after terminate app in iOS. so please suggest me.

Currently I'm using `MZDownloadManager` class in my application
[here is the link](http://github.com/mzeeshanid/MZDownloadManager)

Right now I'm using the above downloading classes and it works perfectly but now my requirement is when user terminate the app than also downloading will continue in background.

Above `MZDownloadManager` is works fine when first user put app in background and than terminate the app. But if user directly terminate the app it is not working.

Please provide proper suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

How About NSURLSession Class ? By using this class you can resume downloading when the app is in background....

Have a Look into Below Link..

http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/#

One more suggestion is don't use other's open source code because you'll get a problem at the time App Submission.

Comment: One more suggestion is don't use other's open source code because you'll get a problem at the time App Submission.

-This is completely false and not a suggestion you should be giving out.

Comment: Reddy you are right here. NSURLSession does this task even if the app is terminated.